# linux dnx (.net execution environment): HTTP 200s with no body content

Tags: asp.net, linux, dnx

I am using dnx on Linux (Ubuntu Server). I have follow that tutorial for installation : https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-linux.html

I remember some month ago that was working very well, but nowaday i got a problem.

I can do dnu restore, and it work well.
When i launch kestrel, the application start :

```
Hosting environment: Production
Now listening on: xxxxx*
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

When i try to launch the website on local, with for example w3m or lynx, i got this answer:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
```

But nothing appended.

On w3m only, while i got this "no error" message, if i type ctrl+c, the website appears! This is really strange, i really don't know what to do, i have already lost too much time on this.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT : I follow these steps :

Follow the tutorial then

use rc1 final on coreclr

```
$dnvm use 1.0.0-rc1-final -r coreclr
```

Go to home

```
$cd
```

Go to my project folder

```
$cd SkyLord/ITI.SkyLord/src/ITI.SkyLord
```

restore packages

```
$dnu restore
```

launch server (kestrel)

```
$dnx web
```

On an other shell, go on website

```
$w3m xxxxx*
```

or

```
$lynx xxxxx*
```

That all.

replace xxxxx by http://localhost:5000
cause yes i can't post more than 2 links -_-

Comment: Can you provide tested steps for someone to reproduce this (assuming that they've already followed the instructions you linked)?

Comment: Sure and thank you for answering fast. I will edit the first post

Answer (score 0):

i just want to notice that i have surrended and restarted the installation on the fresh server from scratch. Notice also that i'm running on an ubuntu server.

Then you can follow those steps :

update packages :

```
$sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade
```

then follow the tutorial. When you instal libuv, run each command separately, don't copy and paste all the block. It can be good assuming you want to see errors ;)
I don't know why but i got some problems on this command line :

```
sudo sh autogen.sh
```

It was because the first line failed, i don't remember if i really typed it, anyway if you got problems just install each dependancies separately :

```
$sudo apt-get install make automake libtool curl
```

Just type apt-get install make, then apt-get install automake etc, to control everything easily.

Right now install your dnx runtime, for me it's rc1 final.

Then, push your project into the server, run dnu restore and dnx web. On the dnu restore i got a problem, some dependencies are unavailable :

```
Unable to locate Dependency Newtonsoft.Json >= 6.0.6
Unable to locate Dependency Ix-Async >= 1.2.5
Unable to locate Dependency Remotion.Linq >= 2.0.1
```

and of course, dnx web can't be runned.

EDIT 18/01/2016 : I deleted the line calling myget sources in my project.json and i have let only the nuget sources. I don't have any source dependency issue now.
The problem still here, i can run the server without any error but i can't access to the website through a navigator.

EDIT : 19/01/2016 : I upgraded libuv to latest version : 1.8.0. But the problem is still here...

Answer (score 0):

I was so dumb !

In the project.json, you have to specify the ip adress of the machine, instead of localhost !

Now the web site is accessible from the network true an internet navigator.
But i still have this strange unworking bullearth when i try to access the website from the local computer with w3c.

EDIT : I have news, alright i can acces to my website from an other computer. BUT, the web page never stop loading. I can see the content but the navigator is still loading for i don't know what.